# iPhone - Polar H7_heart_rate_sensor connectivity using bluetooth

Tags: iphone, ios6, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Please suggest me, whether an iPhone application can connect with external bluetooth devices like polar h7/h6 heart rate sensor fitness belt (http://www.polar.com/en/products/accessories/H7_heart_rate_sensor)?

I am following these links:
http://www.tekritisoftware.com/scan-ble-devices-using-ios-core-bluetooth-framework 
https://github.com/sergiomtzlosa/CoreBluetooth-Demo/

But i am not sure, whether iPhone app will connect to this external fitness belt. Please guide.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be using Bluetooth Low Energy, and you should be able to connect to it with an iDevice with the BLE chip...
If you've already the accessory, you could use LightBlue to connect.

Comment: Before buying the heart rate sensor belt (Polar H7 heart rate sensor), I want to confirm whether I can pair it with iOS device (iOS > 5) using core bluetooth API or not? As it seems from the documentation that polar h6/h7 are LED which is supportable by core bluetooth api. Please suggest?

Comment: Bluetooth Smart means it should work with Bluetooth Low Energy, so with the `CoreBluetooth.framework`

Comment: Thanks larme for your answer, Now i can move ahead with coreBluetooth.framework to access the information of an external device through iPhone. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So: *Bluetooth Smart* is the branded name of *Bluetooth Low Energy*.

Source: [Bluetooth.com](http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/Low-Energy.aspx) and [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy).

 The Apple Sample: *CoreBluetooth Temperature Sensor* and the iOS app *[LightBlue](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=lightblue%20ios&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/lightblue/id557428110?mt=8&ei=qcmUUYTyIYHMPZGXgdgB&usg=AFQjCNHnQlru7ukp6M9MTTlIeewuEJAHXQ&sig2=WH_S-N2Yhx6k4zUJhOHp2w&bvm=bv.46471029,d.ZWU)* (to check/test) are great starts.

Comment: Hi Larme, I am now using the apple sample code for heart rate monitor, and i am trying to pair it with polar h7 heart belt with that application, but its not working for me. It is generating me this warning "<CBConcreteCentralManager: 0x1d577220> is not powered on" and then goes to case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
            return TRUE; block, Please suggest what i am missing.

Comment: It means that Bluetooth is Off... Go to Settings/Bluetooth and switch it on.

Comment: It is enabled in device, i have checked it. It is iPhone 5 with latest ios.

Comment: I have changed my code from [self.manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180D"]]options:nil];
     with
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];
    [self.manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:dictionary]; and its start giving me the heart rate properly. But i want to know that according to bluetooth heart rate have code for 180d, but why not it is searching my device with 180d?

Comment: Don't the scan option to nil. Keep it with the NSDictionary as set. Then, you can put your NSArray with the UUID you're looking for.
FYI: The UUID in this array, work with the key "OR". Indeed, if you're looking for a device that has services UUID 0001 and 0002,, you'll get those with 0001 and 0002 even if it has only one of them.

Comment: I was able to connect to my Polar H7 from my iPhone 5 by modifying the Apple sample code CoreBluetooth Temperature Sensor @Larme refers to. Let me know if you need specifics.

Comment: Hi mharper, I need to do the same thing; connect to both a H6 and H7. Could you tell us the specifics about your modifications? Or is it possible to share the modified sample code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Brabbeldas, are you able to accomplish your requirements successfully? You just have to modify the UUID parameter in apple sample code and it will work.

Comment: Hi @york, I have got it working, I did not use the apple sample code though. Tomorrow I will put some code together and post it here as a full answer.

Comment: Hi @Brabbeldas, good to hear, Please post your logic so that another developers can take help from your efforts.

Comment: @Larme, if the connection is BLE then maximum 6/7 devices can be connected with an iOS device. But recent Polar Team pro app works for 40 sensor which collects GPS based data. Could you please guess how they are collecting data in app from HR sensor ?

Answer (score 2):

Below is the logic for a fully working example to scan for bluetooth HRM devices, discover their services and their characteristics, followed by logic to extract data from notifications.
Hopefully the comments within the code are self explaining.
Within the code I have added some url's to the related bluetooth specs.

The ViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import CoreBluetooth;


#define HRM_HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID @"180D"
#define DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE_UUID @"180A"

#define HRM_MEASUREMENT_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID @"2A37"
#define HRM_BODY_LOCATION_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID @"2A38"
#define DEVICE_MANUFACTURER_NAME_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID @"2A29"

@interface TestHRMViewController : UIViewController <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CBCentralManager *centralManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CBPeripheral *hrmPeripheral;


// Instance method to get the heart rate BPM information
- (void) getHeartBPMData:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error;
- (void) getBodyLocation:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic;

// Instance methods to grab device Manufacturer Name, Body Location
- (void) getManufacturerName:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic;

@end
```

The ViewController.m  file:

```
#import "TestHRMViewController.h"

@interface TestHRMViewController ()

@end

@implementation TestHRMViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Create the CoreBluetooth CentralManager //
    CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    self.centralManager = centralManager;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - CBCentralManagerDelegate

// Method called whenever you have successfully connected to the BLE peripheral //
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    // Set the delegate of the peripheral //
    [peripheral setDelegate:self];

    // Tell the peripheral to discover services //
    // When the peripheral discovers one or more services, it calls the peripheral:didDiscoverServices: method //
    [peripheral discoverServices:nil];

    NSString *connected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connected: %@", peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected ? @"YES" : @"NO"];

    NSLog(@"%@", connected);

}

// Method called when an existing connection with a peripheral is disconnected //
// If the disconnection was not initiated by cancelPeripheralConnection: the cause is detailed in error //
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSString *connected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connected: %@", peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected ? @"YES" : @"NO"];

    NSLog(@"%@", connected);
}

// Method called with the CBPeripheral class as its main input parameter //
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    // Check to make sure that the device has a non-empty local name //
    NSString *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
    if ([localName length] > 0){
        NSLog(@"Found the HeartRate monitor: %@", localName);

        // Stop scanning //
        [self.centralManager stopScan];

        // Store peripheral //
        self.hrmPeripheral = peripheral;
        peripheral.delegate = self;

        // Connect to peripheral //
        [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Device with no localName");
    }
}

// Method called whenever the device state changes //
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    // Determine the state of the CentralManager //
    // (To make sure this iOS device is Bluetooth low energy compliant and it can be used as the CentralManager) //
    if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");

        // Create an array with Bluetooth-services you wish to detect //
        NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:HRM_HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID], [CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE_UUID]];
        // Start scanning for services //
        [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:nil];

    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");
    }
}


#pragma mark - CBPeripheralDelegate

// Method called when the peripheral's available services are discovered //
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{
    // Walk through all services //
    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services){
        NSLog(@"Discovered service: %@", service.UUID);

        // Ask to discover characteristics for service //
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
    }
}

// Method called when the characteristics of a specified service are discovered //
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
    // Check if service is HeartRate service //
    if ([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:HRM_HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID]]){

        // If so, iterate through the characteristics array and determine if the characteristic is a HeartRateMeasurement characteristic //
        // If so, you subscribe to this characteristic //

        for (CBCharacteristic *aChar in service.characteristics){

            // Request HeartRateMeasurement notifications //
            if ([aChar.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:HRM_MEASUREMENT_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]){

                [self.hrmPeripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:aChar];
                NSLog(@"Found heart rate measurement characteristic");
            }

            // Read BodySensorLocation once instead of subscribing to notifications //
            else if ([aChar.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:HRM_BODY_LOCATION_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]){

                [self.hrmPeripheral readValueForCharacteristic:aChar];
                NSLog(@"Found body sensor location characteristic");
            }

        }

    }

    // Check if service is DeviceInformation service for Manufacturer name //
    if ([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE_UUID]]){
        for (CBCharacteristic *aChar in service.characteristics){

            // Read Manufacturer name once instead of subscribing to notifications //
            if ([aChar.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_MANUFACTURER_NAME_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]){

                [self.hrmPeripheral readValueForCharacteristic:aChar];
                NSLog(@"Found a device manufacturer name characteristic");
            }
        }
    }

}

// Method called when you retrieve a specified characteristic's value //
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    // New value for HeartRateMeasurement received //
    if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:HRM_MEASUREMENT_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]){
        // Get HeartRate data //
        [self getHeartBPMData:characteristic error:error];
    }

    // Characteristic value for ManufacturerName received //
    else if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_MANUFACTURER_NAME_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]){
        // Get ManufacturerName //
        [self getManufacturerName:characteristic];
    }

    // Characteristic value for BodySensorLocation received //
    else if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:HRM_BODY_LOCATION_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]){
        // Get BodySensorLocation //
        [self getBodyLocation:characteristic];
    }

}


#pragma mark - CBCharacteristic helpers

// Method to get the heart rate BPM data //
- (void) getHeartBPMData:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    // Get the BPM //
    // https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml //

    // Convert the contents of the characteristic value to a data-object //
    NSData *data = [characteristic value];

    // Get the byte sequence of the data-object //
    const uint8_t *reportData = [data bytes];

    // Initialise the offset variable //
    NSUInteger offset = 1;
    // Initialise the bpm variable //
    uint16_t bpm = 0;


    // Next, obtain the first byte at index 0 in the array as defined by reportData[0] and mask out all but the 1st bit //
    // The result returned will either be 0, which means that the 2nd bit is not set, or 1 if it is set //
    // If the 2nd bit is not set, retrieve the BPM value at the second byte location at index 1 in the array //
    if ((reportData[0] & 0x01) == 0) {
        // Retrieve the BPM value for the Heart Rate Monitor
        bpm = reportData[1];

        offset = offset + 1; // Plus 1 byte //
    }
    else {
        // If the second bit is set, retrieve the BPM value at second byte location at index 1 in the array and //
        // convert this to a 16-bit value based on the host’s native byte order //
        bpm = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(*(uint16_t *)(&reportData[1]));

        offset =  offset + 2; // Plus 2 bytes //
    }
    NSLog(@"bpm: %i", bpm);



    // Determine if EE data is present //
    // If the 3rd bit of the first byte is 1 this means there is EE data //
    // If so, increase offset with 2 bytes //
    if ((reportData[0] & 0x03) == 1) {
        offset =  offset + 2; // Plus 2 bytes //
    }



    // Determine if RR-interval data is present //
    // If the 4th bit of the first byte is 1 this means there is RR data //
    if ((reportData[0] & 0x04) == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", @"Data are not present");
    }
    else
    {
        // The number of RR-interval values is total bytes left / 2 (size of uint16) //

        NSUInteger length = [data length];
        NSUInteger count = (length - offset)/2;
        NSLog(@"RR count: %lu", (unsigned long)count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            // The unit for RR interval is 1/1024 seconds //
            uint16_t value = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(*(uint16_t *)(&reportData[offset]));
            value = ((double)value / 1024.0 ) * 1000.0;


            offset = offset + 2; // Plus 2 bytes //

            NSLog(@"RR value %lu: %u", (unsigned long)i, value);

        }

    }

}

// Instance method to get the body location of the device //
- (void) getBodyLocation:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
{
    // Get the BodySensorLocation //
    // https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.body_sensor_location.xml //

    NSData *sensorData = [characteristic value];

    // Convert the characteristic value to a data object consisting of byte sequences //
    uint8_t *bodyData = (uint8_t *)[sensorData bytes];

    // Determine if you have device body location data //
    if (bodyData){
        // Access the first byte at index 0 in your array //
        uint8_t bodyLocation = bodyData[0];

        // Determine if it is 'Chest' or something else (other values mean other locations, see url) //
        NSString *sensorLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Body Location: %@", bodyLocation == 1 ? @"Chest" : @"Undefined"];
        NSLog(@"SensorLocation: %@", sensorLocation);

    }
    else {
        // If no data is available, log N/A as the body location //
        NSLog(@"SensorLocation: N?A");
    }

}

// Method to get the manufacturer name of the device //
- (void) getManufacturerName:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
{
    // Get the ManufacturerName //
    // https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.manufacturer_name_string.xml //

    NSString *manufacturerName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"ManufacturerName: %@", manufacturerName);

}


@end
```

Comment: Thanks @Brabbeldas, hope it will help other developers :)

Answer (score 2):

Get Swift implementation of POLAR 
https://github.com/msyshani/PolarDemo-for-iOS

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth
import QuartzCore


protocol polarDeledate{

    func updateStatus(bpm:String)
    func updateBPM(status:String)
}


class MSYPolarH7: NSObject , CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {


    let POLARH7_HRM_DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE_UUID = "180A"
    let POLARH7_HRM_HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID = "180D"


    let POLARH7_HRM_MEASUREMENT_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "2A37"
    let POLARH7_HRM_BODY_LOCATION_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "2A38"
    let POLARH7_HRM_MANUFACTURER_NAME_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "2A29"


    var polarDel:polarDeledate?


    //MARK:- Var Init

    var centralManager:CBCentralManager?
    var polarH7HRMPeripheral:CBPeripheral?

    //MARK:- Make Singleton
    class var sharedInstance: MSYPolarH7 {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: MSYPolarH7? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {

            Static.instance = MSYPolarH7()

        }
        return Static.instance!
    }


    func startScanningDevice(){
        let cManager=CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        //cManager.delegate=self

       // cManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([CBUUID(string: POLARH7_HRM_DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE_UUID),CBUUID(string: POLARH7_HRM_HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID)], options: nil)
        cManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
        self.centralManager=cManager
    }


    //MARK:- CBCentralManager Delagates

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        peripheral.delegate=self
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)

        if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralState.Connected {
            print("Connected")
            if let msyPolar = polarDel {
                msyPolar.updateStatus("Connected")
            }
        }else{
            print("Not connected")
            if let msyPolar = polarDel {
                msyPolar.updateStatus("Not connected")
            }

        }
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
        print("dis connected")
        if let msyPolar = polarDel {
            msyPolar.updateStatus("Disconnected")
        }
        self.centralManager?.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : AnyObject]) {
        print("Restored....")
    }


    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
        let localName=advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey]
        if localName?.length > 0 {
            print("Found device is \(localName)")
            self.centralManager?.stopScan()
            peripheral.delegate=self
            self.centralManager?.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
            self.polarH7HRMPeripheral=peripheral
        }

    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {

        if(central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff){
            print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off")
        }else if(central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn){
            print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready")
            self.centralManager?.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([CBUUID(string: POLARH7_HRM_DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE_UUID),CBUUID(string: POLARH7_HRM_HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID)], options: nil)
        }else if(central.state == CBCentralManagerState.Unauthorized){
            print("CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized")
        }else if(central.state == CBCentralManagerState.Unknown){
            print("CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown")
        }else if(central.state == CBCentralManagerState.Unsupported){
            print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform")
        }


    }



    //MARK:- CBPeripheralDelegate Delagates

    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: NSError?) {

        for service:CBService in peripheral.services! {
            print("discover service \(service.UUID)")
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: service)
        }

    }


    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {

        if service.UUID == CBUUID(string: POLARH7_HRM_HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID) {
            for aChar:CBCharacteristic in service.characteristics! {
                // Request heart rate notifications
                if aChar.UUID == CBUUID(string: POLARH7_HRM_MEASUREMENT_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID) {
                    self.polarH7HRMPeripheral?.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: aChar)
                    print("Found heart rate measurement characteristic")
                }else if aChar.UUID == CBUUID(string: POLARH7_HRM_BODY_LOCATION_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID){
                     self.polarH7HRMPeripheral?.readValueForCharacteristic(aChar)
                    print("Found body sensor location characteristic")
                }
            }
        }



        // Retrieve Device Information Services for the Manufacturer Name

        if service.UUID == CBUUID(string: POLARH7_HRM_DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE_UUID) {
            for aChar:CBCharacteristic in service.characteristics! {
                // Request heart rate notifications
                if aChar.UUID == CBUUID(string: POLARH7_HRM_MANUFACTURER_NAME_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID) {
                     self.polarH7HRMPeripheral?.readValueForCharacteristic(aChar)
                    print("Found a device manufacturer name characteristic")
                }
            }
        }

    }


    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {

        // Updated value for heart rate measurement received
        if characteristic.UUID == CBUUID(string: POLARH7_HRM_MEASUREMENT_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID) {
            //print(characteristic)
            //self.getHeartBPMData(characteristic, error:error!)
            self.getHeartBPMData(characteristic)
        }


        // Retrieve the characteristic value for manufacturer name received
        if characteristic.UUID == CBUUID(string: POLARH7_HRM_MANUFACTURER_NAME_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID ) {
            getManufacturerName(characteristic)
        }


        // Retrieve the characteristic value for the body sensor location received
        else if characteristic.UUID == CBUUID(string: POLARH7_HRM_BODY_LOCATION_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID ) {
            getBodyLocation(characteristic)
        }


    }


    //MARK:- CBCharacteristic helpers

   // func getHeartBPMData(characteristic:CBCharacteristic,error:NSError)
    func getHeartBPMData(characteristic:CBCharacteristic){

       //print("Hello")
       // print("characteristic \(characteristic)")

        if characteristic.value == nil {
            return
        }


        let data = characteristic.value
        let reportData = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data!.bytes)
        var bpm : UInt16
        if (reportData[0] & 0x01) == 0 {
            bpm = UInt16(reportData[1])
        } else {
            bpm = UnsafePointer<UInt16>(reportData + 1)[0]
            bpm = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(bpm)
        }

        let outputString = String(bpm)
        print("bpm is \(outputString)")

        if let msyPolar = polarDel {
            msyPolar.updateBPM(outputString)
        }

        //doHeartBeat()

        return

       // return outputString

    }

    func getManufacturerName(characteristic:CBCharacteristic){
        let manufacturerName=NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("Manufacturer is \(manufacturerName)")

        return

    }


}
```