# Why can I not scan for and find my Bluetooth LE heart rate monitor?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, health-monitoring

I've tried multiple programming Xcode projects (such as this code: [iPhone - Polar H7_heart_rate_sensor connectivity using bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16582165/4907229)) to try to scan for my Polar H7 heart rate monitor (HRM) from my bluetooth iPhone 5s with no luck.  I call the scanForPerhiperalsWithServices to specifically search for my heart rate monitor but it doesn't appear to find it since it never subsequently calls the didDiscoverPeripheral method.

How can my BTLE HRM pair with my iPhone and connect to commercial apps (such as Polar Beat and Strava) but not be detected using standard Bluetooth LE API's?

I am new to iOS and Bluetooth and I'm using Yosemite with Xcode 6.3.1 and my iPhone 5s using iOS 8.3.

Comment: As I'm working on my situation, I'm discovering more problems.  It appears that the typical BLE scanner apps CANNOT find my Polar H7 HRM.  That would include apps such as (Punch Through's LightBlue, KST's BLExplorer, and Pally's BLE Scanner).  But they WERE discovering my HRM just yesterday?  How come my HRM is no longer discoverable?  Did a setting change?  What's funny is that my iPhone and commercial HRM apps such as Strava and Polar Beat continue to work fine.  Now I'm really confused!